# Junit test - com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator has not been set

Tags: java, spring, junit, liferay

```
public class CustomServiceImplTest extends TestCase{

    ApplicationContext ac;

    private BeanLocator mockBeanLocator;

    @Test
    public void testCreateCategory() throws Exception {

        CustomService  customService = (CustomService) ac.getBean("customService");
        customService.CreateCategory();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        mockBeanLocator = Mockito.mock(BeanLocator.class);
        PortalBeanLocatorUtil.setBeanLocator(mockBeanLocator);
        CompanyLocalServiceUtil mockCompanyLocalService = Mockito.mock(CompanyLocalServiceUtil.class);
        ac = CustomSpringUtils.loadApplicationContext(new String[] { ""/applicationContext-Services.xml" });
    }   
}
```

I am using basic JUnit 4 and created above test class extending TestCase.

The exception I am getting follows :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  at com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByWebId(CompanyLocalServiceUtil.java:498)
```

The following method customService.CreateCategory(); has calls to Lifery util methods such as CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByWebId and etc.

Please anyone shed some light on this. I really appreciate any help.

Do I need to provide Liferay DS information in spring config file?? OR

Is there any way I could stub out the data ?? 

I am trying to test a ADD operation on one of the Liferay entity class -

```
MBCategoryLocalServiceUtil.addCategory(...)
```

Comment: You can provide the sourcecode of CompanyLocalServiceUtil? I can not find any source code with more than 300 lines. Cheers

Comment: public static CompanyLocalService getService() {
if (_service == null) {
_service = (CompanyLocalService)PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(CompanyLocalService.class.getName());
ReferenceRegistry.registerReference(CompanyLocalServiceUtil.class,
"_service");MethodCache.remove(CompanyLocalService.class);
}return _service;
}private static CompanyLocalService _service;  // I did not provide setService method as it is space constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject/mock `CompanyLocalService` class in `CompanyLocalServiceUtil`. The Liferay way of doing it is:

```
CompanyLocalService service = ..... // mock;
new CompanyLocalServiceUtil().setService(service);
```

The setService is an instance method but is assign value to static field. Don't ask me why it is implemented and designed in such way.

Comment: mockBeanLocator = Mockito.mock(BeanLocator.class);
PortalBeanLocatorUtil.setBeanLocator(mockBeanLocator);
CompanyLocalService mockCompanyLocalService = Mockito.mock(CompanyLocalService.class);
CompanyLocalServiceUtil mockCompanyLocalServiceUtil = Mockito.mock(CompanyLocalServiceUtil.class);
mockCompanyLocalServiceUtil.setService(mockCompanyLocalService);
ac = CustomSpringUtils.loadApplicationContext(new String[] { ""/applicationContext-Services.xml" });
 }   I tried this but still service is null.

Comment: Don't mock `*Util` class, mock only `*Service` and inject it to `CompanyLocalServiceUtil`.

Comment: yeah, got rid of null pointer by instantiating *Util and then injected mocked *Service, but I do have bunch of Liferay Entity calls (Company, User, Group, Category, Role, Resource, permission) in a single method. I am not sure to test my custom service method, it is a good idea and worth going in this way and mocking. I am thinking about injecting all the dependency jars, spring xml files of liferay if possible, so I do not need to mock any data.

Comment: It won't be easy to initialize all liferay dependencies and it'll require database. Usually it's too slow to setup and initialize database for unit tests. If you don't want to mock all liferay services there is another way. If all or at least most of interactions with liferay is encapsulated in some method in your service you can mock only the method to return some static value (instead of using liferay services). You can use partial mock or extend your class and override the method and use subclass in tests.

Comment: most of the Liferay entity calls are in private methods, which called by a public method. I am writing test method for this public method. If I understood your comment, I could do mock and then dummy data returns, as DB and real dependent objects are not available. As I said, Liferay entity calls are scattered in the multiple private methods, I assume, I need to mock and return dummy data in SetUp method. OR I need to go in harder way of DB, "REAL" objects, dependent jars and dependency injection.

Comment: Using DB and real object is last what you should try. I was thinking about [partial mock](http://blog.javabien.net/2009/06/21/mockitos-partial-mocks-testing-real-objects-just-got-easier/) that can be created using [Mockito](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.8.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16). But to make it work mocked methods have to be public or protected, private methods cannot be mocked. You can [here](http://monkeyisland.pl/2009/01/13/subclass-and-override-vs-partial-mocking-vs-refactoring/) read more about subclass and override vs partial mocking.

Comment: `setService` was deprecated in Liferay 6.2